# appending integers to empty NumPy array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append

I have a NumPy array that stores the information of a signal. In the code below I have just created it from random numbers for convenience. Now I need to select positions from the signal array, based on criteria. Again, I have simplified the criteria below, for sake of brevity. I am trying to store those positions by appending them to an empty NumPy array called positions. I know that my use of the NumPy.append() function must be wrong. I tried to debug it, but I cannot find the bug. What am I doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as random

signal = random.randint(1,10000,1000)

positions = np.array([],dtype = int)
for i in range(0,len(signal)):
    if((signal[i] % 3 == 0) or (signal[i] % 5 == 0)):
        print(i)
        np.append(positions,i)

print(positions)
```

**EDIT:**

I actually need this to run **in a for loop**, since my **condition** in the if() is a mathematical expression that **will be changed** according to some rule (that would be way to complicated to post here) if the condition is met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an explicit loop for this:

```
positions = np.where((signal % 3 == 0) | (signal % 5 == 0))[0]
```

Here, `(signal % 3 == 0) | (signal % 5 == 0)` evaluates the criterion on every element of `signal`, and `np.where()` returns the indices where the criterion is true.

If you *have* to append to `positions` in a loop,  here is one way to do it:

```
positions = np.hstack((positions, [i]))
```

Comment: @sebastian: When used in this way, `np.where()` returns a single-element tuple. The `[0]` unwraps the single element.

Comment: I implemented the change. Problem is, my true code is much more complex than the one above. I actually need to run this in a for loop, since the condition in the if() changes (I edited the question).

Comment: @sebastian: `positions = np.hstack((positions, [i]))`